# Подключение .NET библиотек к Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Можно ли подключить к `Xamarin` проекту в `Visual Studio` библиотеки от `Windows`? Или как это работает?

Допустим есть некий сторонний сервис, у него есть `api.dll` для `WP`, `Android`, `iOS`, но нет для `Xamarin`. Можно ли его подключить к `Xamarin.Android` и `Xamarin.iOS`?

Я пробовал подключать, проекты не собираются.

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь смотрите таблицу стандартизации, дабы понять, правильную ли вы версии используя в проектах.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

**Xamarin.iOS** и **Xamarin.Android** могут взаимодействовать либо с такими же проектами либо с .Net Standard/PCL.

Второе. Проверьте, есть ли библиотеки в Вашем проекте, которых нет в этом списке.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/

Comment: насколько я понимаю, там есть библиотека под .NET 4.0 (видимо не PCL/.NET Standard), а также библиотека под .NETCore v4.5 (Windows Store). Выходит, подключить их нельзя?

Comment: Попытайтесь перевести все в один стандарт, или скомпилируйте несколько версий под разные фреймворки